# How do I make sense of integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

How do I make sense of the fact $\int u \ du=uv-\int v \ du$, where $v=\int du$ knowing only as far as calc 2 material?

I know integration is the inverse of differentiation, so if the argument of the integral is itself a derivative and we wish to undo it I can use the fact that
$$(udu)'=u(du)'+du(u)'$$
Integrating both sides, and then once more, I have 
\begin{align*} udu&=\int u(du)'+ \int du(u)' \\ \int u \ du &= \int (\int u(du)')+\int (\int du(u)') \\ 
\end{align*}

But this hasn't been helpful for me, I think, because when I try to use that exact equation on say, the integral of $xe^x$ I have
$$\int xe^x dx=\int (\int xe^x \ dx) + e^x $$

It looks like I'm just one step away from getting the formula I want. What am I missing?

Comment: It's the product rule for differentiation in reverse.

Comment: yeah just integrate both sides of the product rule

Answer (score 3):

Recall the following,

$$\frac{d}{dt} (uv) = u'v + v'u$$

where $u'=\frac{d}{dt}u$ and likewise for $v$. Integrating both sides, we find,

$$uv = \int u'v dt  + \int v'u dt.$$

Now subtract and you have integration by parts.

Comment: The only missing piece here is that, by definition, $u'dt = du$ and $v'dt = dv$.

Comment: Subtract what? I don't see how either part of the sum is equal to $\int (u \ du)$. It looks like you're saying $\int v' vdt$ or $\int v' udt$ is equal to $\int (u \ du)$

Comment: see Charles' comment above for that point

Comment: Ooh now I see it.

Comment: This answer is probably sufficient for OP's question, but I want to mention that this requires differentiablity whereas $\int udv = uv - \int vdu$ still holds without.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to integrate *twice*.  You integrate *once* only.

$$(fg)'= f'g+fg'\implies fg=\int f'g+\int fg'$$ by FTC.